# Entity with lots of relationships with Android Room

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to update my Android knowledge with the new [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture). I'm looking at how to persist data with [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room), but it seems like it is practically unusable if you actually have [relational data](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships) and I'm hoping you can help me understand something I've missed or confirm that Room really doesn't work for any kind of serious relational data.

Here's my problem in as small a nutshell as I can offer.

I've got an app for animal breeders and I have an `Animal` entity. Let's say I have a `Weight` entity which is a record of how much an animal weighed on a given date. An `Animal` has a to-many relationship to `Weight` to create a history of how much they weighed over time.

According to the Room training documentation, I would need to create a 3rd class called `AnimalWithWeights` like:

```
data class AnimalWithWeights(
    @Embedded val Animal: Animal,
    @Relation(
          parentColumn = "AnimalId",
          entityColumn = "AnimalId"
    )
    val Weights: List<Weight>
)
```

and add a function to my DAO like `fun getAnimalsWithWeights(): List<AnimalWithWeights>`.

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM Animal")
fun getAnimalsWithWeights(): List<AnimalWithWeights>
```

But I don't have just one relationship.

My `Animal` entity has relationships to other `Animals` like father, mother, surrogate mother, breeding parter, and relationships to other entity types like `Breed`, `Breeder`, `Buyer`, `DNA`, and to-many relationships for `Weights`, `Notes`, `MedicalTreatments`, `MatingRecords`, `Ultrasounds`, etc.

Unless I'm missing something, it sounds like I need to create a class that is `AnimalWithWeights` and then wrap that in a 4th class called `AnimalWithWeightsAndNotes`

and wrap that in a 5th class called `AnimalWithWeightsAndNotesAndMedicalTreatments`

and wrap that in a 6th class called `AnimalWithWeightsAndNotesAndMedicalTreatmentsAndMatingRecords`

and wrap that in a 7th class called `AnimalWithWeightsAndNotesAndMedicalTreatmentsAndMatingRecordsAndUltrasounds`...

and I haven't even gotten to `...AndFatherAndMotherAndSurrogateMotherAndBreedingParterAndBreedAndBreederAndBuyerAndDNA....`

I'm currently using [ORMLite](https://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) to handle my sqlite persistence and it handles relational data well, but it seems like Room is only really designed to handle flat data.

Am I missing something with Room?

I'd like to be able to use some of the new features like `LiveData<>` so that I can get automatic callbacks when my data is updated and so that's one of the reasons I was looking into Room, but it just seems too rudimentary to be able to handle a realistic relational data model.

Comment: It doesn't make sens ... for ex for showing list you need fx only data from Animal table ... if you show details than you may add method for this like  `loadWeightsForAnimal(animalid)` ... loading whole information at once take time and "eat" resources

Comment: Even setting aside the to-many relationships, on the view screen, I need to be able to show the father's name, mother's name, surrogate mother's name, breeding partner's name, breed name, breeder name, buyer name, DNA name, (and more relationships that I left out of my example), so I'd still need `...AndFatherAndMotherAndSurrogateMotherAndBreedingParterAndBreedAndBreederAndBuyerAndDNA...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your post whether you're aware of possibility to link several `@Relation`s in mentioned auxilary 3rd class. With `Animal` having one-to-many and one-to-one relations to other entities technically you need add just one final class `AnimalWithAllStuff`:

```
data class AnimalWithAllStuff(
    @Embedded val Animal: Animal,
    @Relation(
          parentColumn = "AnimalId",
          entityColumn = "AnimalId"
    )
    val weights: List<Weight>,
    @Relation(
          parentColumn = "AnimalId",
          entityColumn = "AnimalId"
    )
    val notes: List<Notes>,
    ....
    @Relation(
          parentColumn = "fatherId",
          entityColumn = "AnimalId"
    )
    val father: Animal,
    @Relation(
          parentColumn = "motherId",
          entityColumn = "AnimalId"
    )
    val mother: Animal,
    ....
)
```

Technically on each `@Relation` Room internally invokes separate query and if you use `LiveData` Room sets tracker to notify observer on any change in `Weight`, `Notes` and so on.

I doubt though that with that structure you can get, for example, `father`'s and `mother`'s weight, notes and so on.

Comment: Ok, that does help a bit, none of the docs or examples on blogs I have seen showed the ability to combine all these things. The one blog example I found that did talk about multiple relations really did use the crazy composition of this and this and this and this. Even the docs reference `UserWithPlaylistsAndSongs` as a composition of two of these data classes. Ok, I'll give this some thought. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you'll need these crazy compositions if your `Note` class has relation with another class `X`, and that class has another relation with class `Y` and you want to get in your `AnimalWithAllStuff` class all this objects' wrapped hierarchy. It's called `nested relations` in Rom's official docs. Then you really need wrap on and on. As I understood from your post it's not your case.